# How can I solve this array problem on vuejs or any other solution?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a web in vuejs that is *multilanguage*, so far the only idea that has occurred to me is to insert in an array the translations that will then be referenced in the html document using JSX. If someone has a more profitable idea and helps me implement it, I will be grateful.

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="superior-nav">
          <div class="langs">
            <select name="language-selector" id="language-selector">
              <option v-for="lang in langs" :value="lang.value">{{lang.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="contacts">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=""></a><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
              <li><a href=""></a><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
              <li><a href=""></a><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
              <li><a href=""></a><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inferior-nav">
          <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      langs: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "English",
          value: "English"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Español",
          value: "Spanish",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Français",
          value: "French"
        }
      ],
      navItems: [
        {
          id: "en",
          home: "Home",
          about: "About",
          services: "Services",
          team: "Team",
          careers: "Careers"
        },
        {
          id: "es",
          home: "Inicio",
          about: "Sobre Nosotros",
          services: "Servicios",
          team: "Equipo",
          careers: "Trabajos"
        },
        {
           id: "fr",
          home: "Accueil",
          about: "À propos",
          services: "Service",
          team: "Équipe",
          careers: "Carrières"
        }
      ],
      selectedLang: []
    }   
  },
  components: {

  },
  methods: {

    changeLang(){
      var id = this.selectedLang;
      var option = document.getElementById("language-selector")[0].value;
      if(option.value === "English"){
        this.selectedLang[0] == navItems[0]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I have a Select element with their respective values and names. So I need that when the value of the select is English, the content of the page is in English and so on with all languages.
As you can see, I have an array called **navItems** that stores in an object each element of the navigation list respectively.
What I try to do with the **changeLang** method is to save them all in a new array called **selectedLang** and then be called with **JSX** as mentioned above. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add v-model inside your select tag and whatever data will be selected it will automatically save to v-model. Remove this code

```
var option = document.getElementById("language-selector")[0].value; if(option.value === "English"){
        this.selectedLang[0] == navItems[0]
      }
```

and change it to this.

```
this.selectedLang = []
navItems.forEach(lang=>{
    if(lang.id == this.languageSelected){
     this.selectedLang.push(lang) 
     }
})
```

- Add languageSelected = 'es' after the selectedLang:[] //so that english will be the default language that will be selected
- Add languageSelected as v-model in select. `<select v-model="languageSelected" name="language-selector" id="language-selector">`
- Change value of lang object same as the id of navItems